# What other patterns can I use for this singleton?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I have a bit of code which uses a plugin and core model, revolving around four major objects: the `Core`, `Server`, `Logger`, and `Parser`, in slightly particular order.

The `Core` acts as the central factory, with a catch: it's bound to a single render context (much of this is graphics related, but the other details are not important). The objects it creates and manages are specific to that core, and multiple cores can be created with different contexts. Cores can never share resources with each other. The `Core` is initialized from a configuration file; more on this later. The `Core` must have, from its creation, a `Server`, `Parser`, and `Logger`.

The `Server` handles loading and initializing all the plugins, as well as creating objects from them. It acts as a single, in-process plugin server and object registry, similar in many ways to a STA in-process COM server. As plugins are loaded into the process, not a particular `Core`, I'm fairly sure this is appropriate. The `Server` must have a `Parser` and `Logger`.

The `Logger` handles logging messages, particularly errors, to disk. It does very simple pre-formatted file writing, with some basic "log level" filtering. The `Logger` requires a `Parser` for resolving file paths.

The `Parser` handles variable replacement, particularly in paths. For example, a plugin may request the file `$(root)/resources/a.txt` and the `Parser` will replace that with the application's root directory; or `$(startup)/a.txt` for the startup directory. Simple stuff. Variables are contained in the `Parser` itself, and many are specific to the thread. However, a few are tied to a single `Core`, and thus enters the...

Config file. Each `Core` is initialized from a config file, which contains a multitude of settings: plugins for the `Server`, variables for the `Parser`, and a file for the `Logger`. Each `Core` can use a different config file, and most likely will.

In my current model, the `Server`, `Logger`, and `Parser` are singletons. They all must provide a single global instance, accessible from the core and plugins (and each other), potentially before a `Core` has been created. All handle process-level functions, but the `Logger` and `Parser` do handle some `Core`-level functionality.

The issue with this is that, in order to make the `Logger` and/or `Parser` `Core`-specific, the `Server` would then need its own instances, which would be potentially lacking important characteristics (like what file to use for the `Logger`). The `Server` also handles work that is *very clearly* common to the whole process: there's just no way to load a plugin into a single `Core`, that's not how shared libraries work.

In a previous version, I had all four of these created when a `Core` was created, and belong to a specific `Core`. This caused some issues and oddities, however: the `Core` loads itself as a "plugin" when it starts up, but the `Server` had the same lifetime as the `Core`, making this seem odd. The `Parser` has a number of variables that belong to the process: the initial directory, root directory, and so on. The `Logger` *must* precede the `Core` in some way, particularly the plugin-loading stage, so errors can be accurately logged.

My questions then are:

- Is this setup too over-engineered? The separation of responsibility between objects seems good, but perhaps too split.
- What design pattern(s), be it singleton or otherwise, is/are appropriate in this case, for these objects?

Comment: Can you have a fifth Main object that instantiates Core, Server, Logger, and Parser? Then you can have it instantiate a Logger and Parser first, and then pass those objects as parameters to the constructors for Core and Server.

Comment: Let me just restate your problem to make sure I understand it correctly.  Your Server object is a singleton.  You instantiate a number of Core objects and each Core object loads a different config file.  Each Core has a Logger and Parse and the Server also has a Logger and Parser.  The Core's config file has data needed by the Core's Logger and Parser.  Correct so far?  If so, where does the config data for the Server's Logger and Parser come from?

Comment: @RaySaltrelli That one of the problems in one of my ideas, not the current state of affairs. At the moment, the Logger and Parser are also singletons, with some finalization done when a Core is created (adding of variables and such). If the Server was to get its own instances, then the data source would become an issue.

Comment: @jhocking Why? What benefit does that provide over the current model? Having a singleton that creates, holds and passes instances vs having each object be a singleton gives the same end behavior.

Comment: OK, so let me try again :-) The Server is a singleton.  You instantiate a number of Core objects and each Core object loads a different config file.  The Server and Cores all share the same Logger and Parse which are also singletons.  You want the Server to use the Logger and Parser with a certain default configuration and you want each Core to add additional configuration to the existing Logger and Parser from its config file when it is created. Am I getting warmer?

Comment: @RaySaltrelli That's a possible solution. At the moment, only the first configuration is used; for example the Core does `if (!Logger.IsOpen) Logger.Open()` and so on. While the Parser and Logger as singletons is useful for a variety of reasons, it restricts them to single configurations, which is the problem that caused me to reevaluate using singletons.

Comment: So if the Logger and Parser are not singletons and the Server and Cores each have their own instances with different configurations, what problems does that introduce?

Comment: @RaySaltrelli Where do the Server Logger and Parser get their information? Cores will need to share variables with the Server's Parser, a path from the configuration file, for example (with some good reasoning, that could probably be removed). I certainly don't want to log to multiple places, that would make a bug-reporting nightmare.

Comment: It sounds like the biggest problem might be that the config file of the first Core created determines everything.  You might need multiple configuration files, one for global configuration and one for core specific configuration.  This way the Server has what it needs with out relying on any Cores and the Cores can still enrich the Server's configuration as they're loaded since the Server is a singleton.

Comment: @peachykeen For the end user that results in the same behavior, but for the developers that has the advantage of not using singletons. Because you asked this question I assumed you already knew that singletons are kind of bad news, but if you need that explained then that is a whole other conversation. And by "a fifth Main object" I didn't mean another singleton, I'm talking about whatever is the start point for your program's execution.

Comment: @jhocking Singletons aren't innately bad, there is a very valid use case for the pattern, and the Server is it: all the state it governs is process-specific but must be accessible anywhere within the process and there must never be more than one instance. Making it anything else complicates a lot of things. The "start point" is the creation of a core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my points:

1. There is a difference between having only *one instance* of the object in the entire application vs. an object becoming singleton so that any one calling `new()` will magically find `theInstance`.
2. In your case, there is no benefit of having server being singleton because no one is *creating* server other than `main()`. It's just plain simple to have it as ordinary object. Even if it is singleton, it will be called only once!
3. `Parser` should *never* be singleton either for a different reason here. If i understood correctly, `parser`'s only role is when `core` is launched; Ideally it should follow `use-and-throw` pattern rather than `singleton`
4. Even `parser` continues to serve some specific queries till `core` wants it, by design `parser` should be one instance per `core` because same instance of `parser` should never share information about various different `core`s. It makes `parser` dedicated per `core`.
5. Most people design `logger` as a singleton. It is not really much big deal, however, if you are a multi-threaded system a singleton `logger` is a big villain. First off, every singleton needs to be threadsafe. Suppose even if you make it thread safe, every time a `thread x` calls logger it is busy doing `printf` for `thread y` so as a result `thread x` waits whereas ideally you should be worrying about getting the maximum out of your quad-Core system and serve as many requests as possible.
6. Ideally the only genuine case where `logger` should be centralized or singleton is where the exact order of events must be registered one-by-one. For most purposes, different files and messages with their own timestamps are usually better even for debugging.

So for me `Server` (which is one instance) is created by `main()` and `core`, `parser` and `logger` are a tuple that is born and dies per request (always together). Each tuple doesn't know the state or existence of other such tuples, and that is good so that arbitrary number of threads can be instantiated in parallel, (one thread per tuple) without losing scalability but preserving loose coupling.

Only thing is - it means you are not using *any* design pattern! But that's not a bad thing. It is *not* necessary that including a design pattern makes your design necessarily better.

Remember:

> There are really rare reasons where using singleton becomes must;
>   everywhere else, using singleton is always an invitation to problems.

Comment: For **2**, any plugin or most others bits of code may access the Server in order to create objects or load other plugins, but there *must never* be competing servers, hence the use of a singleton. I am well aware of all the implications of the (anti-)pattern, but that object is the ideal use case for it. For **3** , the Parser is also available to any plugin and at any time, but (**4**) it is Core-specific, so trying to move it there will likely help. For **5**, the singleton creation and all calls are thread-safe (all the objects and their methods are, in fact)...

Comment: The log messages are formatted as-needed, so if the Logger can early-out based on severity level, the format will never occur, otherwise the format is triggered, then a brief lock for atomic write. What I do want is for all the log info from a single run of a single process to go into a single file, for a variety of reasons which include **6**. Most logging only happens during error handling, at which point performance is tenth concern to in-order logging (stamped to the ms), making sure the log makes it to disk (the log is flushed if an error is logged), and so on.

Comment: I do think you're onto something with the tuple idea and **4**, potentially with a global variable dictionary instead of a global parser.